# Setting the number of copies before overwrite on subscribed reports?

Tags: reporting-services

We are using Microsoft reporting services in order to generate reports for our customers.

Today we are using the "overwrite" option when writing reports to a file share, one of our customers has now asked if would be possible to keep the last 7 copies of the rendered PDF, instead of replacing the old one each time a new report is generated.

I have looked inside the site settings for subscriptions, and can only find how to limit the number of snapshots, can this setting be used in the described scenario?

My question is: Is this possible to do with settings inside Reporting Services or do we need to use the "increment file names as newer versions are added" and then write some script that removes the old files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to use snapshots, as this will require the users to go onto SSRS reporting site. If you want to keep the PDF's on  a file share you would do exactly as you suggested:

- The the Windows File Share subscription settings select the **Increment file names as newer versions are added** option.
- Run a separate script to select all the files, sort them by date, and remove all but the first 7.